# How to give width and height to a button in Android?

Tags: android, button, height, width

I'm developing a little Android app with some square buttons created dynamically from Java code. I'm using the Absolute.LayoutParams method to give width and height to them, but I get deprecation warnings.

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width,height, 0, 0);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I tried this too:

```
button.setHeight(height);
button.setWidth(width);
```

But it is not working. There is a third way to do it easily and clean?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `AbsoluteLayout`, you need to use `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams`, rather than `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`.

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, 0, 0);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Also note that the proper way to set the width and height of a `View` is to do so via the `LayoutParams`. See `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` and `View.getLayoutParams()`. You shouldn't have to set the width and height manually as you do in your second example.

I strongly suggest, however, that you implement this with a `RelativeLayout` (or `LinearLayout`, etc.) instead... `AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated, and for very good reason. There are so many different Android devices with different sized screens now, `AbsoluteLayout` just won't work across them all. Never, ever, ever using `AbsoluteLayout` is always good practice :).

Comment: if your view layout is fixed, it might also be a better idea to do all of this using XML. your code will look a lot prettier (and it will be easier to make changes later on if you must).

Answer (score 3):

i think it will be

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width,height);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```